# SVN to send emails on commit on Ubuntu 12 server

Tags: ruby, email, svn

I need to set up an svn repos to send out emails after every single commit to a single email address.

There seem to be a few built packages out there that achieve this, but then some forum posts and the svn manual say I just need a simple post commit email hook:

http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/147924/anyone-have-commit-notification-hook-script-that-will-send-email-upon-commit-of#answer-147963

The script in this post is RUBY. Does this mean I need Ruby?

Also on my Ubuntu server I am running sSMTP not a full blown SMTP server, will this matter or will this automatically be picked up as it is with PHP?

Thanks,
John

Comment: If you want to run a Ruby script, then yes you'll need Ruby.  However, SVN hooks can be written in anything.

Comment: When I copied the script from the link above into the post-commit file and changed the permissions, after committing I got an error reading: 'post-commit hook failed(exit code 255 with no output. I had changed the email address accordingly.. does this mean the sendmail failed?